# Pull request with changes in different pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket

Imagine following situation:

Developers A and B are working on the same feature using bitbucket forks. Developer A finishes his work and creates pull request to incorporate changes back to the upstream. In the meantime developer B is working on another part of the same feature and needs to update his fork with developer's A changes - so he merges the branch from colleagues fork to his own fork. Then developer B also finishes his fork and wants to propagate his changes to upstream. What is the preferred way to do this? Since the first pull request is not merged yet when developer B creates pull request it will be showing the changes from developer A as well. Should B wait till A's PR is merged or will the B's PR update to show only B's changes once A's PR is merged or is there another better way?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this, in my opinion, is that when developer A finished implementing the feature that developer B needs he will push this upstream.

Then developer B will pull these changes to his fork and start working.

Then developer A will push his work when he finished and also developer B will do so.

This procedure should not cause any error. Let me know what you think.

Comment: What if B needs the changes from A before they can be merged to upstream? Eg. waiting for code review / approval / ...

Comment: One thing A could do is to push them to his forked repo. You clone the repo from his fork and continue working on it. 

That is just the idea that came to my mind.